# There are infinitely many numbers that can't be written as a sum of a prime and a triangular number

Tags: elementary-number-theory

While having lunch in our cafeteria, some mathematicians told me of a quite interesting problem:

**There are infinitely many numbers that can't be written as a sum of a prime and a triangular number.**

They've said that they all failed to prove that theorem.
Unfortunately, I failed in proving that as well.
Does someone of you know a proof of that? Or is the theorem false at all?

The triangular numbers are given in explicit form as $T_n = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$.

Comment: The difference of two triangular numbers is usually not prime, so usuallt you cannot write a triangular number in this form. You may or may not want to modify your question to exclude that type of response. Also see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1586507/ for this idea.

Comment: In order to improve the quality of the question (which is generally interesting IMO), you can: 1. Include the mathematical definition of *triangular number* (instead of leaving it for the reader to google). 2. Give an example of at least one such number (since it is not that easy to find).

Comment: @quid: Thank you for the link, but I can't see why the difference of two triangular numbers is usually not prime.

Comment: @barak manos: Thank you for your advice. In the link posted by quid, one shows that 2016 can't be written as a sum of a prime and a triangular number.

Answer (score 2):

Take $n < m$. Notice that $d = m(m+1)/2 - n(n+1)/2 = (1/2)(m-n)(m+n+1)$. Say $m > 2$ is even.

If $n < m - 1$ is odd, then $m + n + 1 > 4$ is even, and so $d$ is composite. If $n < m - 2$ is even, then $d$ will have non-trivial factors $(1/2)(m-n)$ and $m + n + 1$.

This leaves $n = m - 1$, yielding $d = m$, or $n = m - 2$, yielding $d = 2m - 1$. So choose $m$ such that $2m - 1$ is not prime, and the numbers $T_m$ fit the criterion. For instance, $m = 6k + 2$ always works, $k \ge 1$.

Comment: m need not be even, only prime. 30k + 2, 3, 5, 8, 12, 14, 18, 20, 25, 26, 28 will work for k ≥ 1. Now the difficult question: Are there infinitely many non-triangular numbers that are not the sum of a triangular number and a prime?

Comment: @gnasher729 there is a conjecture to the contrary by Z.W. Sun.See conj 1.1 in https://arxiv.org/abs/0803.3737

Comment: After some experimentation, I'd suggest that the integers which are not the sum of a triangular number and a prime are the triangular numbers Tn where neither n nor 2n-1 are prime, plus the numbers 2, 7, 61, 211, and 216. For example, for x = 3,247,410,348 x - Tn is composite for a bit over 1,100 of the largest triangular numbers less than x, but x - Tn would have to be composite for over 80,000 triangular numbers.